# Lookout Mobile iPhone wifi security

Tags: iphone, ios, security, wifi, iphone-privateapi

How can "Lookout Mobile Security" (iPhone application - http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lookout-mobile-security-free/id434893913?mt=8) tell if a wifi network is secure or not?
This is private api [How to know the security type like OPEN, WPA, WPA2, WEP, when using Apple80211 api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666696/how-to-know-the-security-type-like-open-wpa-wpa2-wep-when-using-apple80211-a).

Comment: It looks like you linked to the answer right there..

Comment: Well, but how can be on App Store if it uses private api?

Comment: Apple may approve private APIs as they choose, but there is only a slight chance. I suggest you contact the developers of the app, because we are no more enlightened on the subject than you are.

Comment: They are not in the App Store, they are on Cydia (for jailbroken phones) according to your link.